# Cannot read property 'outlets' of null in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to use `routerLink` and `router-outlet` but I'm getting `Cannot read property 'outlets' of null` issue in my Angular 6 project.

I was able to recreate the issue in this simple example Angular 6 project here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dk8i8y

The error comes when a route link is clicked, although the value is hardcoded.

`<a [routerLink]="['/manage', 'plugins' ]" > Plugins </a>`

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this can be done differently, but with a not named outlet this works.

Also when you change routes the components are not recreated again, so you need to subscribe to the route params to get notified when the route changes. In these cases it is often a good idea to use the async pipe, since it takes care of unsubscribing when the component is destroyed. I have updated the Stackblitz below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qppimo

Answer (score 3):

I don't know this will help anyone or not but this issue will come if you have any extra "," in your route array. It will not give you an error in editor or compilation as this is a valid value(undefined) for an array

Here is my previous route

```
   const routes: Routes = [{
        path: "verified-employee-reviews",
        loadChildren: () => import("./verified-employee-reviews/verified-employee-reviews.module").then(m => m.VerifiedEmployeeReviewsModule)
    },
    ,
    {
        path: "verified-reviews",
        loadChildren: () =>
            import("./verified-reviews/verified-reviews.module").then(
                m => m.VerifiedReviewsModule
            )
    }]
```

Here is my new Route

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "verified-employee-reviews",
    loadChildren: () => import("./verified-employee-reviews/verified-employee-reviews.module").then(m => m.VerifiedEmployeeReviewsModule)
},
{
    path: "verified-reviews",
    loadChildren: () =>
        import("./verified-reviews/verified-reviews.module").then(
            m => m.VerifiedReviewsModule
        )
}]
```

Make sure you don't have any extra comma in your route.

Answer (score 0):

Note to anyone else with this problem;

In Angular 7, I've encountered this problem as well when using `ActivatedRoute` to retrieve a non-existent param. For example if you make this call;

```
this.projectId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('projectId');
```

But if that ID is different, or does not exist in your route definitions, you will get this error.

```
          {
            path: 'organize/:id',
            loadChildren: '../project-organize/project-organize.module#ProjectOrganizePageModule'
          },
```

In this example, my route specifies a param named `id`, but I am using `projectId` in my ActivatedRoute request.

Answer (score 0):

An unnecessary comma in the `tabs-routing.module.ts` file throws the same error. Just make sure you have enough number of commas in your file.

Answer (score -1):

```
<a *ngIf="post" [routerLink]="['/posts',post?.id]">{{post?.title}}`</a>
<a *ngIf="!post">{{post?.title}}</a>
```

Comment: Explaining your code and how it solves the problem will raise the quality of your answer, and help learning users.